# What is the best way to make database backups of Docker Swarm MariaDB containers?

Tags: ansible, backup, docker-swarm, database-backups

I have servers that are configured with Ansible. All applications and their dependencies on those machines are running within containers of a user namespaced Docker Swarm.

The legacy infrastructure used a regular perl script (`mysql-zrm`) and a cron job to backup the MySQL/MariaDB databases but I guess

1. Nowadays there might be better alternatives than `mysql-zrm`? `mysqldump` is fine, too but `mysql-zrm` also sends email in case errors occured and it also should do some proper date related naming as well as keeping just a certain amount of backups.
2. I guess a cron would be still suitable, but what's the recommended way of dumping from a Docker Swarm container as the name is generated? Something like `docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name="some-container-name*") mysqldump … > some_dump.sql`? Or rather creating a short living backup container in the same Docker network?

Or maybe something entirely different?

Comment: Hey. Have you found a solution to this? Thanks

Comment: Well, I went with the solution I mentioned in 2. It works for me but it doesn't feel reliable.